# Sending submatrices using MPI_Scatterv and MPI_Type_vector and MPI_Type_create_resized

Tags: c++, matrix, resize, mpi, submatrix

On the root there is a matrix with size r*height and r*width. There are r*r processors and I want to send a widht*height submatrix to each of them.
In my lecture i am learning about the commands in the title, but i am a little confused about how to use them.

I allocate the matrix and the submatrix called tile on every process.
I create a datatype for the submatrices called "tile".
I resize it, so we can interleaf the different tiles.

```
// Allocated on every process, fixed in real code
std::vector<double> everything (height*width*r*r); // r is 3 later, because we have 9 submatrices
std::vector<double> tile (height*width); // width and height are both 3 here
MPI_Datatype vector_t, tile_t;
MPI_Type_vector(height, width, width*r, MPI_DOUBLE, &vector_t);
MPI_Type_create_resized(vector_t, 0, width, &tile_t); 
MPI_Type_commit(&tile_t);
```

Here is an example of how i want to scatter the matrix:
each number should later become one submatrix. There are 3 submatrices in one "row".
The resizing of tile_t makes it, so that the first tile starts at index 0, the 2nd starts at index 3, and the 3rd starts at index 6. This way they interleaf.

```
-------------
|000|111|222|
|000|111|222|
|000|111|222|
-------------
```

What i dont get is how i can use scatterv to make a bigger jump. A potential 4th submatrix in the next "row" would need to start at index 27.
Here is how i imagine scatterv should be used on the below matrix.

```
-------------
|000|111|222|
|000|111|222|
|000|111|222|
-------------
|333|444|555|
|333|444|555|
|333|444|555|
-------------
|666|777|888|
|666|777|888|
|666|777|888|
-------------
```

```
int dspls = [0,1,2,9,10,11,18,19,20];
int counts = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

MPI_Scaterv(
    everything.data(),
    &counts, // one tile already has 9 INT in it
    &dspls,
    tile_t, // send type
    tile.data(),
    9, // recv count
    MPI_INT,
    rank_of_root,
    MPI_COMM_WORLD
)
```

Now i understood it this way: To calculate the adress of a certain thing scatterv wants to send, it does this:

displs[i]*sizeof(tile_t)

and because i resized tile_t, this expression equals:

displs[i] * width = displs[i] * 3

or it does

displs[i] * width * sizeof(int) = displs[i] * 3 * sizeof(int)

What should i put into dspls, for the code to make sense?

Comment: Please write a self-validated [mcve] and either leave some blanks or describe what is not working.